# Convert Reactive Forms Value Into Model Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using `Reactive Forms` and I want to convert the value of `formGroup` into Model class object. Please give me some solutions for it. and also I want to send only `password` fields not `confirmPasword`. I also mentioned my model class .

Service.ts

```
objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}
formModel = this.fb.group({
    FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
    LastName: ['', Validators.required],
    Emails: this.fb.group({
      EmailID: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      ConfirmEmail: ['', Validators.required]
    }, { validator: this.compareEmails }),
    OrgName: ['', Validators.required],
    OrganizationType: ['', Validators.required],
    City: ['', Validators.required],
    PhoneNo: ['', Validators.required],
    PostalAddress: ['', Validators.required],
    Passwords: this.fb.group({
      Pwd: ['', Validators.required],
      ConfirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }, { validator: this.comparePasswords })
  });
```

Model Class

```
export class RegisterModel {
    Active: number;
    Address: string;
    Amt: number;
    CityID: number;
    Country: string;
    EmailID: string;
    FullName: string;
    ID: number;
    PhoneNo: string;
    PostalAddress: string;
    Pwd: string;
    constructor(init?: Partial<RegisterModel>) {
        Object.assign(this,init);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = this.formModel.value
```

**vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, instead of using a Class for defining `RegisterModel`, I would recommend you to use an Interface instead.

```
export interface RegisterModel {
  Active: number;
  Address: string;
  Amt: number;
  CityID: number;
  Country: string;
  EmailID: string;
  FullName: string;
  ID: number;
  PhoneNo: string;
  PostalAddress: string;
  Pwd: string;
}
```

On your component/service that requires the above interface, we first initialise the `objRegisterModel` property.

```
objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = {} as RegisterModel;
```

To get the values of your Reactive Form `FormGroup`, you can simply do this:

```
this.formModel.value
```

If you want to get only the password, and I assuming you are referring to the `Pwd` property,

```
this.formModel.Passwords.Pwd
```

Comment: Please check model class

Comment: @WebMaster thanks for that. Regarding your `RegisterModel`, where do values for properties such as `Active`, `Address`, etc come from? I can't seem to find the corresponding matching Form Controls on the FormGroup

Comment: yes may be, but it should set those values which are exactly the same as model property, @wentjun

Comment: @WebMaster yes I know, but there is no `Active` `Address` `Amt` `cityId` on your reactive form?

Comment: I removed all extra properties from model class and try again but it's behavior was same.

Comment: Did you assign the form values to `objRegisterModel`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your model class don't have all the fields as in form.
I consider it as your mistake, you should add all fields in the model then make and use some mapping function like

```
mapping(group: FormGroup){
Object.keys(group.control).forEach(key =>{
const abstractControl = group.get(key);
if(abstractControl && abstractControl instanceof FormGroup){
//call recursively
mapping(abstractControl);
}
else{
if(key !== 'ConfirmPassword')
this.objRegisterModel[key] = abstractControl.value;
}
}//end of forEach
}//end of func
```

Now you just need to call this function passing object of FormGroup.
Hope it helps you